# SugarCRM and Laravel : custom Authentication driver

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, sugarcrm, laravel-5

I'm currently developing an app using Laravel. What I want to do, is to link this app to a SugarCRM app.

A simple workflow could be this:

User arrives to the app (Laravel app), enters its credentials
-> Credentials are sent to SugarCRM
-> if credentials are ok, the user is logged into the Laravel app.

**Long story short, SugarCRM is used for the authentication to my Laravel App.**

To do this, I developed a custom driver to my Laravel app.

**The problem is:**
If I quote the [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/master/extending#authentication) about custom Auth driver:

```
retrieveByCredentials: This method should not attempt to do any password validation or authentication.
```

Laravel Auth system requires to check first if the user exists in the base, with "no attempt to do any password validation or authentication".

But to do any kind of request to SugarCRM, I must authenticate first.

How should I deal with this without writing too dirty code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the docs mean there is that function shouldn't validate or authenticate credentials for your application. So if that function is called it shouldn't log that user in, but just return their credentials.

Its fine to authenticate to your external service so you can interact with their API.